# Drawing arrows alongside a tabular

Tags: tikz-arrows

i'm trying to create to arrows alongside a tabular like in the following picture :

[image]

This is what i've tried to do, but the result is far from the one in the picture

```
\tikzstyle{my arrow} = [draw=cyan!75, very thin, single arrow, minimum height=6cm, shape border rotate =#1, fill=gray!10]`

\begin{frame}
\begin{tabular}{| c |}
\hline
    fadd1\\
    inop1\\
    iadd1\\
    fmul1\\
    inop2\\
    fadd2\\
    lstore\\
    fnop1\\
    fmul2\\
    inop3\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\node at (-0.25,1) [my arrow=90] {\rotatebox{90}{}};
\node at (8,1) [my arrow=-180] {\rotatebox{-90}{}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
```

Any ideas ? Thanks for your help

Comment: welcome to tex.se! please extend your code snippet to complete but small document beginning with `\documentclass{beamer}` and ending `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

like this?

[image]

it is simple just draw all (not used `tabular`):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{ Recurrent Neural Networks (RNNs)}
    \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    box/.style = {draw, align=left, inner xsep=5pt, outer xsep=3ex},
                    ]
\node (box) [box]  {fadd1   \\
                    inop1   \\
                    iadd1   \\
                    fmul1   \\
                    inop2   \\
                    fadd2   \\
                    lstore  \\
                    fnop1   \\
                    fmul2   \\
                    inop3 };
\draw[-stealth] (box.north west) node[above] {start} -- 
                (box.south west) node[below] {stop};
\draw[-stealth] (box.south east) node[below] {start} --
                (box.north east) node[above] {stop};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```